# Pulling a repo on Raspberry PI boot?

Tags: linux, boot, bash, git

I'm getting stuck on this : I try to make a git pull on a repo on Raspberry boot.

What I've done so far :

**In /etc/rc.local :**

```
su pi -c bash /home/pi/boot.sh
```

**My boot.sh script :**

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
cd /home/pi/Sites/node-raspberry-pi/
/usr/bin/git pull
exit 0
```

The thing is : **I'm not familiar with bash script**, this is just some copy paste of code I've found. 
It works properly when executed directly : `bash /home/pi/boot.sh` but not on /etc/rc.local, so I guess this is a permission issue ?

EDIT : I updated the code.

Comment: One difference is that when executed from `rc.local`, the script will be run as root, not as you. Also, the run-time environment is different, and things like `PATH` may not be set up at that point. Try editing the script and adding the full path to git - i.e. change `git` to `/usr/bin/git` (or wherever it exists on your system). All other commands in that script are built into the shell and shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Ok, thanks for noticing that git couldn't be available at this point. You also say that the script will be run as root, how to run it as pi user at this point ?

Comment: I've never done that myself, actually, but it looks like the solution is to use `su` or `sudo` to do that. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17956151/how-to-run-a-command-as-a-specific-user-in-an-init-script) and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12973777/how-to-run-a-shell-script-at-startup). Did adding the full path solve your problem?

Comment: I updated the code above with what I tried : su pi -c and full path to git. Doesn't work :/

Comment: There's a few issues I see here - you need to run git *after* networking comes up, which is tricky with traditional init systems. I'd otherwise consider using cron with the @reboot 'time' setting to run the bash script.

Comment: I did a new cron task (crontab -e) on @reboot, it works as expected. Can you post an answer explaining that ?

Comment: @enguerranws Can you first post the cron task to answer your own question and help other people as well?